# Show a series converges uniformly using M-test

Tags: calculus

I want to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$. This is the power series and I know that it converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Can I use this as the bound for the absolute of the terms and conclude by the M-test that the series converges uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Comment: It does not converge in $[0,1]$, but in $[0,1)$ (pointwise). Moreover it converges uniformly on every compact set of $[0,1)$, but it does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c<1$ be a positive real number. Then, for $x\in[0,c]$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty x^k<\sum_{j=1}^\infty c^k=\frac c{1-c}$$

But the series does not converge on $[0,1]$ and does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$, as Crostul said.

Answer (score 1):

Since the series is not convergent at the point $1$, I consider convergence in $[0,1)$. Now, all you can say is that for any compact subset $K \subset [0,1)$ there is uniform convergence on $K$, since you can apply M-Test with $\sum_n (\max K)^n < + \infty$.

To see that there is no uniform convergence on $[0,1)$ note that for all $n$
$$\sup_{x \in [0,1)}  \left| \frac{1}{1-x} - \sum_{k=1}^n x^k\right| = +\infty$$
so that this quantity cannot tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.